# Easier way to run Python program in Pdev console without typing commands?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using Pydev for Eclipse to program Python. Is there any way to restart a program running after I make changes other than retyping

```
>>>runfile ('filename')
```

Every single time?

Also, is there any way to start the program more easily than the above for the first time?

NOTE: I am not trying to run it in the console, I am trying to run the python in the interactive console where I can input commands into. Pressing the Run button at the top of the IDE DOES NOT run the program in the interactive console.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> r = partial(runfile,"filename")
>>> #now you can just type r()
>>> r()
```

a better idea is to use some interactive console that you can invoke from your code

```
C:\>  easy_install q
```

then at the top of your file add

```
import q
```

and at the end of your script enter

```
q.d()
```

this will halt your script and open a shell where you have access to anything from your script then you can just use the run button to run it ...

as an aside i did not downvote your other question ... I just answered in the comments based on how I understood your question

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion on my last question...